# make a function for 15 month after today

Tags: php, function, date

i have a function to show today date like this

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

//Menampilkan tanggal hari ini dalam bahasa Indonesia dan English
$namaHari   = '';
$namaBulan = array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
$today = date('l, F j, Y');
$sekarang = $namaHari[date('N')] . date('j') . "-" . $namaBulan[(date('n')-1)] . "-" . date('Y');
?
```

problem: how to make function to show date after 15 months after today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the answer just i found
15 months mean 1 year 3 months so can split it into 1 for year and 3 for month
so, code be like this

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$m = 3;
$n = 1;
$nextN = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + $m, date("d"), date("Y") + $n);
echo date('d-m-Y', $nextN);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use simple +15 months in strtotime:

```
$nextdate = date('l, F j, Y', strtotime("+15 months", $today))
```

Comment: The idea is kind of correct, but the code is wrong: The first parameter of `date` is the format and the second of `strtotime` is a timestamp (not necessary here though).

Comment: You are right about the first param. However, for second one, he may want to use different date set in $today in the future projects.

Comment: Maybe, but `$today` in the OP's question is a formatted date, so using the same variable name is confusing / not correct. But the idea is good and the OP should be able to take it from there...

Comment: I don't understand what does $sekarang mean but if you are giving it a +15 months date, use date('j',strtotime($nextdate)) and so on.

Comment: @andricoga `$namaHari` is emtpy, so `$namaHari[date('N')]` is not going to work. You should look into `strftime` if you want to localize dates: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: I have a problem to make date after convert in Indonesia time. you can see in $sekarang = $namaHari[date('N')] . date('j') . "-" . $namaBulan[(date('n')-1)] . "-" . date('Y');

the result of echo"$sekarang"; like this 1-06-2013 i want 1-09-2014, 15 months after today